# Python exit asyncio/websockets process with Ctrl-C

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I have a problem stopping python processes using asyncio and websockets, not sure which one is the issue.  If I run this code then sometimes Ctrl-C doesn't do anything and I need Ctrl-Z which seems to just send the process to background because it doesn't close the websocket server port in use.

How do I allow stopping of the process with Ctrl-C?

```
async def handle_messages(websocket):
    async for message in websocket:
        await websocket.send(message)

async def start_server():
    async with serve(handle_messages, "localhost", 7878):
        await asyncio.Future()  # run forever

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(start_server())
```

In case you run into this issue this is how you stop it on mac at least:

```
kill -9 $(lsof -ti:7878)
```

Comment: I could not replicate the issue. What python & library versions are you using? Both this code, and the code this seems to be based on from the [websockets documentation](https://pypi.org/project/websockets/) responds perfectly fine to `KeyboardInterrupt` on Debian Linux with python version 3.11.2 and websockets version 11.0.1

Comment: @Egeau Mac OS Ventura 13.2.1 | python 3.10 | websockets ^11.0.1

Comment: could not replicate the issue on Debian 11 and Fedora 37 (my desktop and the laptop that was turned on anyway) with python 3.10 and websockets 11.0.1. I am presuming you have tried a different terminal emulator and such to make sure the `KeyboardInterrupt` is properly sent to the python interpreter?